# How to removeMessage from TCHMessages with Twilio

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api

How to use this func in Twilio?

```
(void)removeMessage:(nonnull TCHMessage *)message
           completion:(nullable TCHCompletion)completion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, fetch all old messages using `getLastMessages` which will return you `[TCHMessage]`. Then, select the particular `TCHMessage` object which you want to remove. Finally,

```
//For TwilioChatClient
channel.messages?.remove(message, completion: { result in
      print(result)  
})

//For TwilioConversationsClient
channel.remove(message) { result in
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Its showing error and says,
Value of type 'TCHChannel' has no member 'remove'

Comment: Can you please confirm your Twilio version... ? Is it TwilioChatClient OR TwilioConversationsClient..?

Comment: I am using TwilioChatClient

Comment: I have updated the answer above. 

FYI, Programmable Chat(TwilioChatClient) will no longer be available or supported after July 25, 2022. Instead, we'll be focusing on the next generation of chat: Twilio Conversations. Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/sdk-download-install